# Makefile on Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to use makefile on Windows 7 x64 with Cygwin. 
I type "make" and the error that i get is:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Makefile:

```
 CC = g++
 CFLAGS = -g -Wall -pedantic
 HDRS = node.h stack.h
 SRCS = stack.cpp main.cpp
 OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRCS))

 proj3:$(OBJS)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)
 %.o: %.cpp $(HDRS)
   $(CC)    $(CFLAGS) -c $<
 .PHONY:clean
  clean:
-rm -f *.o *~ *core* proj3
```

None of the files are missing.

Comment: Type in `ls` and make sure `Makefile` is listed.

Comment: Your highly-inconsistent formatting here makes me think that your `Makefile` is _also_ incorrectly formatted. Make sure each recipe line starts with a tab, and all other lines do not. (I don't think it will lead to the error you've reported, but it surely won't be happy either.)

Comment: It just first time i'm posting here code, so i didn't indent code as it in makefile.But this makefile works fine at Linux Fedora Red Hat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question SOLVED:
i had makefile in my directory as Makefile.mak
I typed in Cygwin

> make -f Makefile.mak

Answer (score 1):

Type "make proj3" to run make successully.

Comment: If no target is specified then make will build the first target found in the makefile.  I don't think your answer will work.