# CygWin make fail with white text

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I have cygwin installed and want to run `make` on a Makefile.
I have `make` installed: GNU Make 4.0

I navigate to the dir with the Makefile in it and run `make`.
As soon as I do it dispalys:

```
User@Computer ~/c/Users/Name/Documents/GitHub/Project/build/CMakeFiles
$make
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.xxxx]
Copyright........ All rights reserved.
```

My text has also changed to white and it seems to resemble the default 'cmd' style, rather than the cygwin one. Typing `make install` does the same. I have to reset my terminal to revert to the default cygwin style.

Comment: Not 100% surre but i think you need the (-f) after make eg (make -f filenaname) --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110231/makefile-on-cygwin --  http://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Comment: Tried using the (-f) but didnt work, the same issue happens. Thanks for the links though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is in [MinGW32 make command on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556823/mingw32-make-command-on-windows).

> If you use cmake ... -G "MinGW Makefiles" you will need to call
>   mingw32-make.

I've got almost exactly the same problem. what i did was simply close my cygwin window, open a windows terminal, called "mingw32-make.exe" under the folder with Makefile, in your case it will be under "~/c/Users/Name/Documents/GitHub/Project/build/CMakeFiles" folder