# MY computer can't find my makefile on Cygwin (windows)

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to run the make utility of cygwin, and it keeps telling me that "***No targets specified and no Makefile found. Stop"

I don't get it. This is my makefile if it helps, it's called Makefile.mak:

```
TestSet.out: TestSet.o Set.o
    g++ -o TestSet.out TestSet.o Set.o

TestSet.o: TestSet.cpp Set.h SetInterface.h
    g++ -c TestSet.cpp

Set.o: Set.cpp Set.h SetInterface.h
    g++ -c Set.cpp

clean:
    rm TestSet.out TestSet.o Set.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is my makefile if it helps, it's called Makefile.mak

Well that's your problem then.

That isn't one of the names that `make` looks for by default.

You either need to rename the file or use `make -f Makefile.mak`

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Arguments

You should also make sure you have the man-pages installed for Cygwin, then you can run `man make` and you will see:

> If no -f option is present, `make` will look for the makefiles `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order.

That would also have answered your question, because it says nothing about files named `Makefile.mak`

Comment: Ahhh, Okay. I guess my professors makefile had that naming convention and I thought mines was supposed to have it too. Thanks. Can you tell me why my question got a down vote? Am I not asking questions correctly?

Comment: Probably for not doing any research, for example reading the man page for `make` before asking the question. A search would also have found http://stackoverflow.com/q/8110231/981959 which answers it (although only partially IMHO)